# Creating an application registration to access Azure REST API under enterprise agreement

Tags: azure, active-directory

Sorry if this is off-topic but I haven't been able to find any information on it anywhere else. I'm trying to create an application registration that will allow a batch process to access the Azure REST API on my behalf.

Normally, this is pretty simple: just create the user, give it API permissions to what you need, add a secret and then insert the tenant ID, application ID and secret into a request against the `/token` endpoint, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token).

I have done that and gotten the access token but, when I try to get all the billing accounts associated with the enterprise agreement, by calling `https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts?api-version=2020-05-01` I get no information back. Also, when I try to access a particular billing account back, by calling `https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{account_id}?api-version=2020-05-01`, I get the following error and a 403 response code:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "User is not authorized to access billing account '{account_id}'."
    }
}
```

So, essentially the application user was created from an enterprise agreement account but can't access enterprise agreement resources from the API. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application registration should have any of the below roles to access the billing accounts information:

1. Service Administrator
2. Co-administrator
3. Owner
4. Contributor
5. Reader
6. Billing reader

You can assign any of the above roles from the **Access Control (IAM)** to the application registration

Comment: That is very helpful but does the user who creates the application registration need to have any particular role? Does the user have to create the registration in a particular directory? Can this operation be done from the Azure Portal or is the EA Portal necessary as well?

Comment: The user needs to have access to create an app registration. The app registration needs to be created in your active directory which is associated with your subscription

Comment: Right, but I need the registration to have access to all subscriptions under the EA billing account. So, which subscription do I associate it with?

Comment: You can associate the application registration to multiple subscriptions. In the each subscription, you can assign any of the above roles to this application registration

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of that. Do you have any relevant Microsoft documentation for this?

Comment: check if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/assign-roles-azure-service-principals